Decrypt/Modify Password of Realm Tag in Server.xml file of Tomcat - LDAP
I have tried extending the JNDIRealm class to first print/get connection password by override getPassword() method and then using getConnectionPassword method. However, its not working and different set of errors.
Requirement: Decrypt the password on the fly in Realm Tag of server.xml file for Tomcat 9. I'm able to do that for Resource Tag using BasicDataSourceFactory but not for Realm Tag.
Note: I dont want decrypting logic, just basic functionality to print current connectionPassword and replace with decrypted password.
Below the Realm Tag in Server.xml
***<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator" changeSessionIdOnAuthentication="false" /> 
<Realm className="org.test.CustomJNDIRealm"
connectionURL="ldap://ldap.TEST.com:3268"
authentication="simple"
referrals="follow"
connectionName="SA-TEST-Archival"
connectionPassword="encrypted_password"
roleSearchAsUser="false"
userSearch=" (sAMAccountName={0})"
userBase="dc-test,dc=com"
userSubtree="true"
roleSearch" (member={0})"
roleName="cn"
roleSubtree="true"|
roleBase="OU=Service Accounts, OU=Services, OU=TEST Resources,DC=TEST,DC=com"/>***

Below is the Java Class which is being compiled into JAR file and being pasted in Tomcat/lib folder.
import org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomJNDIRealm extends JNDIRealm {
@Override
protected String getPassword (String username) { 

//String password= super.getPassword (username);
String password = getConnectionPassword();
System.out.println("++++++The current password LDAP Realm Tag "+password);
return password; 
}
}

Error:
Now I'm getting errors like CombinedRealm not configured with CredentialHandler  and SetPropetiesRule.begin Match .. failed to set property for all the properties inside realm tag.
Note: This is vendor based application and we have no control over application code. Only we have control over Tomcat and we need to implement the masking of password in LDAP connectivity in Realm tag.

Where did you configure the CombinedRealm. Why is there a Valve element before your realm declaration. Realm is generally configured inside Engine element.

I have not configured CombinedRealm anywhere. This is how its configured in server.xml as per our Active Directory Team. They provided sample and we put it there and it started working.

Here's the answer, it was solved by overriding setConnectionPassword method instead I was trying previously to directly modify in constructor and other methods.
import org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm;

public class CustomJNDIRealm extends JNDIRealm {
@Override
protected void setConnectionPassword(String connectionPassword) {

    String realmTagPassword = connectionPassword;

    System.out.println(realmTagPassword);

    return super.setConnectionPassword("newPassword); 
    }
}

